# how to delete directory even if files inside are used by other application in python

Tags: python, windows, file

I am using shutil module for deleting a directory, but one of the file in the directory is used in one application but still is there any way to over come this error and delete the direcotry

The path given from deleting the directory is till temp_custom and Testing.img is a file which is being used in other application.

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process:
>   u'D:\MaharashtraIDSI\TempFolder\temp_custom\Testing.img'

Comment: Unlike Unix, Windows doesn't allow anonymous files. That means even if  "Testing.img" was opened with delete sharing (i.e. `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`), which is uncommon but possible, the name doesn't actually get unlinked from the "temp_custom" directory until the the last kernel file object is closed (including kernel pointer and user handle references). That said, if (and only if) it was opened with delete sharing, you can rename the file to another directory on the same volume (e.g. "D:\MaharashtraIDSI\TempFolder\Testing.img"). Then you can remove the "temp_custom" directory.

Comment: It seems even the case with delete sharing can't be handled by the current `shutil.rmtree`. On Windows, `os.unlink` calls `DeleteFile`, which doesn't unlink anything. It sets a delete disposition on the file. Any handle with delete access can unset that disposition, and the file isn't unlinked until the last reference is closed. Once the disposition is set, no new references are allowed, so it's too late to move the file out of the way. Thus the `onerror` handler can do nothing to work around the exception raised by `os.rmdir`. A totally different approach is required.